# Can the reason for posting a bounty and the bounty poster be added to featured questions?

Tags: feature-request, bounty

[Featured questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) have more information than is currently available through the [/questions/featured API route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/featured-questions).  Could the following be added?

- The user who posted the bounty (since it's no longer the same as the owner of the post).
- The reason selected for posting the bounty.
- The custom message entered by the bounty poster.

The main piece that I'd like to see is the reason selected for the bounty.  My immediate use case is for [@BountyBot](https://twitter.com/bountybot), a Twitter bot that tweets interesting bounty questions.  I'd like to filter out bounties posted for the "Reward existing answer" reason, since I only want to draw attention to questions that need new answers. (The other pieces of information would be useful if I were posting on Facebook, Google+, a blog, or anywhere that allowed more than 140 characters.)

Comment: `question.bounty_user` was added in 2.2, but you're still out of luck on the actual bounty reason.

Answer (score 3):

While not perfect, some of what you're looking for is currently available.  The bounty owner user ID and custom message will be in the results if you [supply a filter that returns `question.notice`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/featured-questions#order=desc&sort=activity&filter=!9j_cPf5rN&site=stackoverflow&run=true), since the notice visible during the bounty should be the one associated with the bountying user.

This won't give you the high-level bounty reason though, and if they picked a preexisting option the `notice.body` field will just be a blank `<p>`. The best you could do right now would be to weed through [/posts/{ids}/revisions](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/revisions-by-ids) and find the relevant information, and then parse it out of the HTML.

Given that that's extremely hacky, I think making the changes you're suggesting would be a good idea.